# code to know wifi is enabled or not and bluetooth is on or not in iphone

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me the code to know wifi is enabled or not and bluetooth is on or not in iphone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enabled, or connected to a network? See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability does not seem to differentiate between Bluetooth and WiFi. If you have WiFi off and BT on as in connecting to a peer but not wanting to be connected to WiFi, you'll get an indication that WiFi is actually on when you don't want it to be....e.g. a private peer-to-peer session w/o WiFi interference.